# Python: create for-loop until two lists match

Tags: python, list, match

I am trying to match two lists until they match:

So let's say I have

`bought = [12, 10, 5]`

`sold = [4, 6, 3, 2, 12]`

Eventually, I want to create a for-loop over both lists that keeps looping until all numbers match. So it would find all current matches and keeps creating splits for numbers that do not match

In the above example, it would start with 12 being a match for both lists. Then there is 10 which does not match anything but the closest element in the other list is 6, leaving behind 4 which is also a match from the other list.

The above would then eventually become

`result = [12, 6, 4, 3, 2]`

I was wondering whether there is a Python function such as `intersections` that can maybe be of help to do this efficiently?

Rules:
1. Sum of two lists is always equal

Comment: Is the ordering of the results list important?

Comment: I am not sure why the 3 and the 2 are in the result. but you might want to take a look at `set`; `{12, 10, 5}.intersection({4, 6, 3, 2, 12}) == {12}`; `{12, 10, 5} == set([12, 10, 5])`

Comment: What should return if the numbers left is not are not in the list?

Comment: No order is not important. And 3 and 2 are in the result because we have 5 in the other list. 5 must then be split into 3 and 2 to match the two lists. We can split 5 into 3 and 2 but we cannot add 3 + 2 to get five (if we assume these lists are quantities with prices not shown)

Comment: post your code - don't just ask people to deliver a solution. b) what if the inputs are [5, 9] [7, 7]? I'm assuming sum(bought)==sum(sold), but that's not enough to solve all inputs with the operations you allowed.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Not trying to only :) Simply trying to see if there is some package/function that does the trick more quickly then doing it manually

Comment: Also, the sum of each list is always identical

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you need to decompose each element `b` from `bought` into elements `s1, s2...` from `sold` with the condition `b = s1 + s2 ...`. To achieve this, I suggest to use combinations. I will enumerate every combinations I can do with elements of `sold`, for example `[4], [6,3], [4,2,12]... etc` until the sum correspond with an element from `bought`.

For your example, `12` matched with `12`, `10` with `6+4`, and 5 with `3+2`. If you had `11`, it would match with `6+3+2`.

```
from itertools import combinations

bought = [12, 10, 5]
sold = [4, 6, 3, 2, 12]
sold = sorted(sold, reverse=True)

result = []
for b in bought:
    stop = False
    for i in range(1, len(sold)+1):
        for c in combinations(sold, i):
            if sum(c) == b:
                result += (c)
                stop = True
                break
        if stop:
            break

print(result)
# [12, 6, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: test case [5,9][7,7] test case [20, 10, 5, 5][5, 5, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10]